# How to add option of adding a missed record here? (vba Access)

Tags: vba, ms-access

Here's my code to add data from the form to existing records in table with the same SampleN. I wish to add an option

- to create new record in that table if there is no `!SampleN = i` with that `i` and then
- to carry out all the same following procedures.

I have no idea how to insert the addrecord line. Please help. Any improvements  would also be an asset!

```
Public Function copydata(forma As Form, i As Integer)
    Dim dtb As DAO.Database
    Dim tabl As Recordset
    Dim flag As Boolean

    Set dtb = CurrentDb
    Set tabl = dtb.OpenRecordset("SamplesProcessing")

    forma.Refresh

    With tabl
        .MoveFirst
        Do Until .EOF
            If !SampleN = i Then

                .Edit

                Select Case forma!Procedure
                    Case 1       'Before treatment
                        ![W of raw sample] = forma!SampleMass
                        ![ChemTreat operator] = forma!UserName

                    Case 2       'Fraction
                        ![W of fraction used] = forma!SampleMass
                        ![ChemTreat operator] = forma!UserName

                    Case 3      'After first burnng
                        ![W after opened carbonisation] = forma!SampleMass
                        ![ChemTreat operator] = forma!UserName

                    Case 4       'After second burning
                        ![W after closed carbonisation] = forma!SampleMass
                        ![ChemTreat operator] = forma!UserName

                    Case 5        'After chem treatment
                        ![W after chem treatment] = forma!SampleMass
                        ![ChemTreat operator] = forma!UserName
                        ![HCl treatment] = True

                    Case 6        'Combustion
                        ![W of C for reaction] = forma!SampleMass
                        ![W of Li for reaction] = forma!LiMass
                        ![Synthesis operator] = forma!UserName

                    Case 7        'Distillating
                        ![W of BenzeneAndScint] = forma!BenzeneMass
                        ![PercentofBenzene] = forma!BenzenePercent
                        ![Distilaltion operator] = forma!UserName

                    Case 8        'Synthesis
                        ![Synthesis operator] = forma!UserName

                    Case 9        'H2SO4 treatment
                        ![H2SO4 treatment] = True

                    Case 10        'HCl treatment
                        ![HCl treatment] = True

                    Case 11        'KOH treatment
                        ![KOH treatment] = True

                End Select
                If IsNull(forma![ProcDate]) = False Then
                    !LastOperDate = forma![ProcDate]
                End If

                If IsNull(forma!Comments) = False Then
                    If IsNull(!Comments) = True Then
                        !Comments = forma!Comments
                    Else
                        !Comments = !Comments + "; " + forma!Comments
                    End If
                End If

                .Update
            End If
            .MoveNext
        Loop
    End With

    Set tabl = Nothing
End Function
```

Comment: [This outlines each step](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb243801(v=office.12).aspx) so you would just need an `Else` clause to the `If !SampleN = i Then` statement to run the `.AddNew` method of `tabl`.

Comment: Oh yes, I tried do do that first, but there is some problem with Loop I guess...

Comment: Is "SamplesProcessing" a table or query?

Comment: It is a table..

Comment: If I understand correct my code, then it does the following: it finds the SampleN equal to i going from the first to the last record and when it finds the equal record it does select case etc, so in this view I should write addrecord somewhere after the Loop, but in that case I am to repeat the select case etc again, I think it's not good(

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The loop is cut out entirely, using `.Seek` to jump directly to an existing record or rerouting using `.NoMatch` in the event a record does not exist. (Sorry for reformatting, I got tired of scrolling)

```
Public Function copydata(forma As Form, i As Integer)

    Dim dtb As DAO.Database
    Dim tabl As Recordset

    Set dtb = CurrentDb
    Set tabl = dtb.OpenRecordset("SamplesProcessing")

    forma.Refresh

    With tabl
        'Locate existing record
        .Index = "SampleN"
        .Seek "=", i
        If .NoMatch Then
            .AddNew
            !SampleN = i
        Else
            .Edit
        End If

        'Now pass parameters
        Select Case forma!Procedure
            Case 1       'Before treatment
                ![W of raw sample] = forma!SampleMass
                ![ChemTreat operator] = forma!UserName
            Case 2       'Fraction
                ![W of fraction used] = forma!SampleMass
                ![ChemTreat operator] = forma!UserName
            Case 3      'After first burnng
                ![W after opened carbonisation] = forma!SampleMass
                ![ChemTreat operator] = forma!UserName
            Case 4       'After second burning
                ![W after closed carbonisation] = forma!SampleMass
                ![ChemTreat operator] = forma!UserName
            Case 5        'After chem treatment
                ![W after chem treatment] = forma!SampleMass
                ![ChemTreat operator] = forma!UserName
                ![HCl treatment] = True
            Case 6        'Combustion
                ![W of C for reaction] = forma!SampleMass
                ![W of Li for reaction] = forma!LiMass
                ![Synthesis operator] = forma!UserName
            Case 7        'Distillating
                ![W of BenzeneAndScint] = forma!BenzeneMass
                ![PercentofBenzene] = forma!BenzenePercent
                ![Distilaltion operator] = forma!UserName
            Case 8        'Synthesis
                ![Synthesis operator] = forma!UserName
            Case 9        'H2SO4 treatment
                ![H2SO4 treatment] = True
            Case 10        'HCl treatment
                ![HCl treatment] = True
            Case 11        'KOH treatment
                ![KOH treatment] = True
        End Select

        If IsNull(forma![ProcDate]) = False Then
            !LastOperDate = forma![ProcDate]
        End If

        If IsNull(forma!Comments) = False Then
            If IsNull(!Comments) = True Then
                !Comments = forma!Comments
            Else
                !Comments = !Comments + "; " + forma!Comments
            End If
        End If
        .Update
    End With

    Set tabl = Nothing

End Function
```

Comment: There may be an even faster way of getting rid of `DCount` and properly handling `.FindFirst` when a record cannot be found.

Comment: Wow! Looks pretty better than with the loops, thank you!

Comment: Please let me know if it works for you and kindly mark as answer if you decide to use it. Glad to help!

Comment: There's some problem with
    .FindFirst "[SampleN] = " & i
Can't yet understand, what's wrong but it doesn't work :(

Comment: I updated `.FindFirst` to `.Seek`. Sorry for the trouble, I forgot how to do it. I replaced the `DCount` with `.NoMatch` in the event that `i` represents a new record. I've never actually used `.Seek` before, but I used the [documentation](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/ff836416.aspx) and believe this should work.

Comment: Well, after renaming the index name of SampleN I've finally checked out your version of the code, and it works perfectly, thank you, Chrisopher!!!

Answer (score 0):

I think I've solved the problem by adding the new loop, look:

```
Public Function copydata(forma As Form, i As Integer)
Dim dtb As DAO.Database
Dim tabl As Recordset
Dim flag As Boolean

Set dtb = CurrentDb
Set tabl = dtb.OpenRecordset("SamplesProcessing")

forma.Refresh


With tabl
Do Until flag = True

    .MoveFirst
 Do Until .EOF
    If !SampleN = i Then

        flag = True
        .Edit

            Select Case forma!Procedure
                Case 1       'Before treatment

                    ![W of raw sample] = forma!SampleMass
                    ![ChemTreat operator] = forma!UserName

                Case 2       'Fraction

                    ![W of fraction used] = forma!SampleMass
                    ![ChemTreat operator] = forma!UserName

                Case 3      'After first burnng
                    ![W after opened carbonisation] = forma!SampleMass
                    ![ChemTreat operator] = forma!UserName

                Case 4       'After second burning
                    ![W after closed carbonisation] = forma!SampleMass
                    ![ChemTreat operator] = forma!UserName

                Case 5        'After chem treatment
                    ![W after chem treatment] = forma!SampleMass
                    ![ChemTreat operator] = forma!UserName
                    ![HCl treatment] = True

                Case 6        'Combustion

                    ![W of C for reaction] = forma!SampleMass
                    ![W of Li for reaction] = forma!LiMass
                    ![Synthesis operator] = forma!UserName

                Case 7        'Distillating

                    ![W of BenzeneAndScint] = forma!BenzeneMass
                    ![PercentofBenzene] = forma!BenzenePercent
                    ![Distilaltion operator] = forma!UserName

                Case 8        'Synthesis
                    ![Synthesis operator] = forma!UserName


                Case 9        'H2SO4 treatment
                    ![H2SO4 treatment] = True

                Case 10        'HCl treatment
                    ![HCl treatment] = True

                Case 11        'KOH treatment
                    ![KOH treatment] = True

                 End Select
               If IsNull(forma![ProcDate]) = False Then
                    !LastOperDate = forma![ProcDate]
               End If

               If IsNull(forma!Comments) = False Then
                   If IsNull(!Comments) = True Then
                     !Comments = forma!Comments
                   Else
                   !Comments = !Comments + "; " + forma!Comments
                   End If
                End If

                .Update

        If .EOF = True Then
            flag = False
        End If
End If

.MoveNext
Loop

If flag = False Then
    .AddNew
    !SampleN = i
    .Update
 End If

Loop
End With

Set tabl = Nothing
End Function
```